# How to deal with: 'An JNi error has occurred, check your installation and try again'?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:889)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1005)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:551)
```

Comment: Any one is there to help me out...
not able to solve it tried by installing maven,added path for JDK/JRE
still facing the same issue

Comment: Please provide : code, input, expected output, actual output. And format code (4 spaces indentation). Then we can try to help.

Comment: This is the small program I am trying to execute
package java;

public class Helloworld{

public static void main(String[]args){
int a=10;
int b=20;
System.out.println(a+b);
}
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your package name.

[You can't have java as a package name as it's prohibited.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

So if you have this:

```
package java; 

public class Helloworld { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int a = 10; 
        int b = 20; 
        System.out.println(a + b); 
    } 
}
```

For example, it needs to be something like this:

```
package mypackagenamethatisnotthewordjava; 

public class Helloworld { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int a = 10; 
        int b = 20; 
        System.out.println(a + b); 
    } 
}
```

Also ensure you rename the folder your code is in to match the package name declared in the class.

Comment: what package name I need to write apart from by writing java@dknejs

Comment: Don't put your files inside a folder called java.